# What is a "Failed to create hard link: File exists" error?

Tags: linux, visual-studio-code, ssh, hardlink

I'm trying to do a SSH login from VSCode using the Remote SSH extension and I'm getting this error. It is working fine when I login from my GIT terminal.

The error stack:

```
[20:44:36.547] > \ln /root/.vscode-server/bin/a5d1cc28bb5da32ec67e86cc50f84c67cc690321/vscode-rem
> ote-lock.root.a5d1cc28bb5da32ec67e86cc50f84c67cc690321.target /root/.vscode-serv
> er/bin/a5d1cc28bb5da32ec67e86cc50f84c67cc690321/vscode-remote-lock.root.a5d1cc28
> bb5da32ec67e86cc50f84c67cc690321
> 
[20:44:36.555] > ln: failed to create hard link ‘/root/.vscode-server/bin/a5d1cc28bb5da32ec67e86c
> c50f84c67cc690321/vscode-remote-lock.root.a5d1cc28bb5da32ec67e86cc50f84c67cc6903
> 21’: File exists
> Installation already in progress...
> e6e07fdafb38##24##
> 
[20:44:36.555] Received install output: e6e07fdafb38##24##
[20:44:36.556] Server installation process already in progress - waiting and retrying
[20:44:36.827] "install" terminal command done
[20:44:36.827] Install terminal quit with output: 
[20:44:37.557] Resolver error: 
[20:44:37.560] ------
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after updating VScode.

Not sure if this is the correct solution but it does work:

1. Login to your server via another ssh program like PuTTY, because your file is located in the root user home directory you'll need to login as root to do this.
2. Delete folder `a5d1cc28bb5da32ec67e86c` from `/root/.vscode-server/bin/` directory.

Found the answer here:

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/2507